# Case Statement in SQL Server which can be used in SSRS

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a query in the following way

```
SELECT     
    CASE WHEN @Show_Subtotals = 'False' THEN 'True'  
         ELSE <This is what i needed figured out> (True or False) 
    END AS HideDetails
```

I am not sure how to display multiple value in the else. I am using this sql statement as Datasource for a SSRS report which has cascading parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `display multiple value`?

Comment: a case can't return multiple values for one row.  what value do you need returned in the else, and what conditions make that value acceptable?  so `ELSE NULL end`? `ELSE WHEN @Show_subtotals = 'True' then 'False' else NULL End`  I for one don't understand the requirement.  Sample data with expected output may help clairifiy

Comment: But you can nest a case when to another one

Comment: So I have a parameter called show_Subtotals which is a radio button. There is another parameter Hide_Details which is dependent on Show_Subtotals. So when show-subtotals is false then the use does not have the option to show any details, as a result the Hide-details is false.

Comment: But when show-totals is true then the user can decide whether they want to hide_details to be true or false ( these are the multiple values). Hope this explains my issue better.

Comment: So you just need a compound statement?  `Else when @show_Subtotals = 'True' and @hide_Details = 'true' then 1 else when @show_Subtotals='True and @Hide_Details='False then 0' end`?  again example data with expected results from the SQL would help  Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898575/nested-iif-or-switch-statement-syntax-needed-correctly

Comment: @AMani: "So when show-subtotals is false then ... Hide-details is false." in your first comment contradicts the condition `WHEN @Show_Subtotals = 'False' THEN 'True'` in your question. Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to display `True` only when `@Show_Subtotals` is False, and both `True` and `False` (as separate options) when `@Show_Subtotals` is True, try:

```
select 'True' AS HideDetails UNION ALL
select 'False' AS HideDetails WHERE @Show_Subtotals = 'True'
```

Comment: No idea how you got that from the question but nice job Mark.