# SSRS Multiple IIF Statements with DateDiff

Tags: switch-statement, iif, nested-if

So, I referenced this article - [Nested IIF or SWITCH Statement syntax needed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898575/nested-iif-or-switch-statement-syntax-needed-correctly)

However, when trying to execute what seems like a simple background color change based on values, I get an "Contains error: BC30201 Expression Expected."

Here is my code:

```
=IIF(DateDiff("d",Fields!Cfs_DueDate.Value,Today())>0 And Fields!statuscode.Value=200002,"CornflowerBlue", Nothing) OR =IIF(DateDiff("d",Fields!Cfs_DueDate.Value,Today())>0 And Fields!statuscode.Value=1,"Red",Nothing) OR IIF(DateDiff("d",Fields!Cfs_DueDate.Value,Today())>0 And Fields!statuscode.Value=2,"Red",Nothing)
```

Anyone know of what would cause this error, as it's not v very explicit. I've tried multiple versions of nested IIFs and a few SWITCH tries.

I'm sure it's something easy. Any help is much appreciated.

TS

Answer (score 0):

found it. Too many "=" (right in front of second "IIF")

Thanks!