# Summing up columns in SSRS with expressions

Tags: expression, calculated-columns, ssrs-tablix, subtotal

I am looking for some help totaling up a column. This column is using expressions from other columns to get its total.

This is the expression I am using:

```
=IIF(avg(Fields!UOS_2017.Value) <= 0, sum(Fields!PROD_HRS.Value) * - 1, 
((avg(Fields!BUD_PROD_HRS___UOS.Value) * avg(Fields!UOS_2017.Value)) - 
sum(Fields!PROD_HRS.Value)))
```

I want to sum this column.

I do want to note that this expression does work but only if the UOS_2017 column has a zero value. I do not know what to do.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S19p.png) is what my design view looks like.

I am also going to attached the results.
[These are the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goeqI.png)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to add this as an answer, but could you try one of these and see what happens?  I am not familiar with avg function, but if you're pivoting data you may have to add sum/avg outside of if statement as well:

```
=SUM(IIF(avg(Fields!UOS_2017.Value) <= 0, sum(Fields!PROD_HRS.Value) * - 1, ((avg(Fields!BUD_PROD_HRS___UOS.Value) * avg(Fields!UOS_2017.Value)) - sum(Fields!PROD_HRS.Value))))


=SUM(IIF(avg(Fields!UOS_2017.Value) <= 0, (Fields!PROD_HRS.Value) * - 1, ((avg(Fields!BUD_PROD_HRS___UOS.Value) * avg(Fields!UOS_2017.Value)) - (Fields!PROD_HRS.Value))))
```

Comment: Also, try  doing IIF within IIF for avg(Fields!UOS_2017.Value) > 0 and see if it works.

Comment: will you please elaborate on using IIF within IIF for avg(Fields!UOS_2017.Value) > 0?  thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898575/nested-iif-or-switch-statement-syntax-needed-correctly    .  This is what I meant.  Try using nested IIF that would also say IIF value > 0 then do this, else nothing.

Comment: After reading another forum looks what I am trying to accomplish requires nested aggregates, the average of a subtotal. Nested aggregates are not currently supported.  The person helping with this gave a work around that worked for anther person; however, it isn't working for me.